# Gnome Schedule cannot run hdparm

Tags: gnome, cron, hdparm

I have set up a cron job that should execute

```
hdparm -y /dev/sda >> /var/log/diskspindown.log 2>&1
```

[image]

When testing it running it via "Run selected task" it executes fine and logs

```
/dev/sda:
 issuing standby command
```

but when executed on schedule it doesn't work and logs

```
/bin/sh: 1: hdparm: not found
```

Comment: try to use full path (`which hdparm`). Cron does not have to have all the paths set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use full path (`which hdparm`). Cron does not have to have all the paths set up.